# A line of code is looping after reading from accelerometer in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is the only problem I keep running into in my app. n=0 by default and will be set to 1 if the gravity value from the accelerometer will be above a certain value. Once n=1 (the gravity detected is high enough) the method "action()" will be called. Since the gravity value from the accelerometer changes really fast I needed to call action() and wait a little bit before changing n back to 0 or action() will be called a few times in a row.

I tried to use sleep() after calling action and before changing n to 0 but it didn't work. I then tried to use the count down timer for 5 seconds and it just looped action(); really fast for 5 seconds before stopping. It might be my lack of understanding of the android count down timer which is weird because I used it in other parts of my code and it worked perfectly.

```
    if(n == 1){
        if (state == true) {
            action();
            new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    n = 0;
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }
```

I just need a way for action() to be called only once and then set n to 0 in order to be ready for another read from the accelerometer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to achieve and this is probably just going to be a Homer Simpson "D'oh!" moment for you...

When n=1, you want to call `action()`, well then `action()` will continue to be called as along as n=1 and state=true. Your countdown timer will keep n=1 until 5 seconds have passed, at which time it gets set to zero preventing `action()` from being called. Furthermore, your creating a new countdown timer over and over again, for as long as n=1 and the state=true.

What you actually want to do is immediately set `n` to zero and `state` to false. If `n` becomes 1 again the `state` will prevent `action()` from being called. Then after your countdown finishes set the `state` back to true, which will allow `action` to be called again. If `state` is being used elsewhere then you will probably need another Boolean variable to use as your control. This way the accelerometer can set `n` to 1 whenever it wants but you won't care until the `state` is true.

```
if(n == 1){
    if (state == true) {
        n=0;
        state=false;
        action();
        new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            }

            public void onFinish() {
               state=true;
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm embarrassed, I did try to set n to 0 right after but it looped and that's when I went the wrong direction trying to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The @DigitalNinja answer has a better fit for your posted code - but consider this alternative:

Define a class:

```
public class ActionTrigger {

   private int latchTimeInMillis;
   private long lastTrigger = 0;

   public ActionTrigger(int latchTimeInMillis)
   {
      this.latchTimeInMillis = latchTimeInMillis;
   }

   /** Invoke 'action' on first trigger or after desired interval. */       
   public void trigger()
   {
      long cTime = System.currentTimeInMillis();

      if ((cTime - lastTrigger) > latchTimeInMillis)
      {
         action();
         lastTrigger = cTime;
      }
   }

}
```

During your code initialization create an instance:

```
ActionTrigger myActionTrigger = new ActionTrigger(5000);
```

And your OP code becomes:

```
// if current gravity reading exceeds threshold
if(n == 1) {
    // the associated 'action' only gets called initially or after desired interval
    myActionTrigger.trigger();
}
```

If you want to generalize the `ActionTrigger` and allow for different "action"s then you can define a callback mechanism in the constructor such as:

```
public interface ActionTriggerCallack
{
   public void onTrigger();
}
```

And add the callback as a constructor parameter

```
public ActionTrigger(int latchTimeInMillis, ActionTriggerCallback cb) {...}
```

and instead of directly calling 'action' call:

```
    cb.onTrigger();
```

and change the original initialization:

```
ActionTrigger myActionTrigger = new ActionTrigger(5000, 
        new ActionTriggerCallback() {
            public void onTrigger() { action(); } 
        });
```

Comment: Thank you! My app is mainly to learn java and android development and that definitely helped.